# Man pages, syscalls, and libc

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls, glibc

Why is `epoll_create` not listed as a library function (man pages, section 3), but `accept` is? While both functions are provided by `libc` and both refers to kernel syscalls?

I know that "why" questions are not usually welcomed, but it's my way to ask for a better fine-grained understanding on the relationship between those concepts and the criteria for adding something to section 2 and/or 3, and the relationship between libc and syscalls (because libc is, after all, who implements the interface with the kernel itself for C programs. So, as I understand, ALL syscalls are library functions, because the libc library is who provides all of those functions; or is there exceptions to my explanation?).

Comment: *So, as I understand, ALL syscalls are library functions*  Well, the ones that are exposed by libc pretty much **must** be library functions.  And even the ones called "syscalls" don't always wrap the the actual system call you'd think.  For example, the `open()` library function actually calls the `openat` system call on Linux.  "Syscall" or "library function" is a minor, almost-totally-irrelevant distinction.  You will rarely if ever care at all.  Making a big deal over the difference is like arguing "hood" vs "bonnet".

Comment: Syscalls are library functions that always make a 'call' on a kernel feature.   So all syscalls are library functions, but not all library functions are syscalls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in the Linux man pages project, the main criterion for which section should document a given function is described in [the introduction to section 3](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html):

> Section 3 of the manual describes all library functions excluding the library functions (system call wrappers) described in Section 2, which implement system calls.

[The `accept` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/accept.3p.html) you likely came across is in section “3p”: it’s part of the POSIX Programmer’s Manual. POSIX doesn’t distinguish between “pure” C library functions and system calls; it describes [system interfaces](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html) without concerning itself with *where* they’re implemented.

As to your subsidiary question, a few system calls don’t have library functions. As a general rule, new system calls don’t get wrappers immediately; on top of that, some system calls such as [`init_module`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/init_module.2.html) aren’t destined to get wrappers at all, at least not in the GNU C library.

Comment: I would also recommend reading the [preface](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/frontmatter/preface.html) for the POSIX documentation (see _"Interface, Not Implementation"_),  the [System Interfaces](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) section, and the [System call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/xrat/xbd_chap03.html#tag_01_03_00_59) definition.

Comment: And it's also worth mentioning that `epoll_create` is not defined by POSIX.

Comment: FWIW, on Ubuntu, `manpages-dev` looks to have both in section 2 ([accept](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man2/accept.2.html), [epoll_create](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man2/epoll_create.2.html)), while [accept in 3p](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man3/accept.3posix.html) looks to be in `manpages-posix-dev`. If that package happens to be not installed, they'd likely get the one from 2 for `accept()` also (well, that's what I saw on the system I tried). And of course if `epoll_create()` isn't POSIX, it wouldn't be in the latter one.